# Other possible ways for SQL injections?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sql-injection

I have an ASP.NET page running in SSL and the checking happens in the code-behind.

I've done the following to prevent sql injection:

1. Included RegEx to filter out unnecessary/hazardous characters (basically, it now only allows 0-9, a-z, and A-Z).
2. Using queries which would look something like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = @Username...".
3. I've also added account lockout so you only have a limited tries available.

After the IBM AppScan to test the vulnerabilities, it seems I've only fixed the Blind SQL Injection and not the Authenticated Bypass.

Is there anything that I've missed that's causing me to fail the vulnerability test?

UPDATE:

```
...

bool bUser = FilterInput(txtUsername.Text);
bool bPass = FilterInput(txtPassword.Text);

// check for restricted characters
if (bUser && bPass)
   Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
...

public static bool FilterInput(string text)
{
    // check if string contains only letters and numbers
    return (Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"));
}
```

anything not within the a-zA-Z0-9 characters should throw a 'false' and would cause the page to redirect/refresh the login page.

The DB queries are all using parameterized queries and the login works correctly. no problem about that part.

Comment: Your question subject doesn't seem to be related to the actual question you've ended up with. You fixed the SQL injection with #2; the parameterised query.

Comment: Treated correctly, there are no hazardous characters. Option 1 is pointless and should be entirely mitigated by option 2.

Comment: It might be an idea to provide a bit of info on "Authenticated bypass". A search for `ibm appscan "authenticated bypass"` ( http://www.google.com/search?q=ibm+appscan+%22authenticated+bypass%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a ) in Google yields only this question.

Comment: @spender Wow; that's some fast indexing!

Comment: Google chums through SO at quite a rate, eh?

Comment: That's what I thought. Changing the queries into parameterized format should have worked but it's still throwing the "Authenticated Bypass using SQL Injection" result.

Comment: Yes, but what does "Authenticated Bypass using SQL Injection" mean? Link please.

Comment: Is it telling you what code is problematic?

Comment: @Andrew It says it's the password but i'm doing the same thing on both username and password. To be more specific my question should probably be: What other way could the AppScan use to "induce" SQL Injection? There's details on the AppScan test results that it was able to get pass the login.aspx via injection which is really puzzling.

Comment: Can you post the code from the login.aspx which handles checking the username and password?

Comment: Are you letting users log in with a system account by chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there were 2 DB queries on the code the wasn't updated into parameterized queries.

Parameterized queries were enough to prevent SQL injection so the other steps/features are a bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the first thing that you did and just use `SqlCommand.Parameters` as explained below:

[SQL Injection vs. Lethal Injection / Protection Against SQL Injection](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/sql-injection-vs-lethal-injection-protection-against-sql-injection)

I always use multiple *Connection Strings* in order to access a database and each of them has different roles: **reading**, **writing**, **execution**. When you do that, you make sure that if the attack is being made successfully on a read action, the attacker cannot do someting other than reading (which is still bad but better than modifying)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I know. I am just telling that first thing he did makes no sense and the second one will take care of everything.

Comment: Agreed; #1 is unnecessary (and needlessly limiting).

Comment: true, but as long as the test passes and the customer want that feature, we can't remove it... for now.